# How to name a audio file when saving into server with POST

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've being developing a solution for my webpage with Django and javascript, it's a record button so that the user can send feedback and I can store it into the server.

The plan is putting a text input where the user can introduce its name and a file is created with that name. This is my code by now. Can anyone help me with this?

> Python views.py

```
def voice_request(request):
    f = open('./Grabaciones/file.wav', 'wb')
    f.write(request.body)
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse('audio received')
```

> Javascript part

```
function sendData(data) {
  let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  let response=fetch("/salud/voice_request/", {
  method: "post",
  body: data,
  headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome at SO.

You have to offer some text input form to the user in order to enable him to send some context.  On the backend site, you would then push the data to the database using a Django `model` which is basically the toolbox for handling data in Django.

Kindly refer to the docu to get a deep dive into it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/